# How find and remove a piece of code from a XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" (...) >
   <w:body>
      <w:tbl>
         (...)
      </w:tbl>
      <w:sdt>
         (...)
      </w:sdt>

      vvvvvvvv
      <w:p w14:paraId="7A11D" w14:textId="7777777" w:rsidR="003B12D0" w:rsidRDefault="003B12D0" w:rsidP="003B12D0">
         <w:pPr>
            <w:rPr>
               <w:sz w:val="18" />
            </w:rPr>
         </w:pPr>
         <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
               <w:sz w:val="18" />
            </w:rPr>
            <w:br w:type="page" />
         </w:r>
         <w:r>
            <w:t />
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
      ^^^^^^

      <w:sectPr w:rsidR="0094346E" w:rsidRPr="000947D4" w:rsidSect="009B7919">
         (...)
      </w:sectPr>
   </w:body>
</w:document>
```

c#:

```
XDocument doc = outputDocument.Document;
XNamespace nameSpace = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");

var result = doc.Descendants().Select(x => x.Element(nameSpace + "p"));
```

This code returns me all the elements containing the < p > tag.
It would be cool if I could find an element that has a tag:

```
<w:r>
  <w:t />
</w:r>
```

and delete the entire object with the closest parent.
The code above is between vvv and ^^^

Comment: How about to use XSLT for the task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
    XNamespace nameSpace = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");

    var nodesWithTagP = doc.Descendants().Select(x => x.Element(nameSpace + "p")).Where(x => x!=null);
    foreach(var nodeWithTagP in nodesWithTagP)
    {
        var nodesWithTagR = nodeWithTagP.Descendants(nameSpace + "r");
        foreach (var nodeWithTagR in nodesWithTagR)
        {
            var nodesWithTagT = nodeWithTagR.Descendants(nameSpace + "t");
            foreach (var nodeWithTagT in nodesWithTagT)
            {
                 if(nodeWithTagT.Descendants().Count() = 0)
                 {
                     //Here you can use nodeWithTagP
                     nodeWithTagP.Remove();
                 }
            }
        }
    }

    doc.Save(filename);
```

Comment: Yes, it looks good, but I only need to delete those where the tag is <w: t />. There is a <w:t> in many places in my document, but I only want to delete the one where it is empty (<w:t />)

Comment: Maybe you need to add one more test before delete, test if there is no descendants for the node with tag T :

Comment: I have updated the answer